# Python 3 - correct way to write to .html without TypeError

Tags: python-3.x, string, byte, typeerror

```
# save-webpage.py (To write first 100 characters of html source into 'simple.html')

import urllib.request, io, sys
f = urllib.request.urlopen('https://news.google.com')
webContent = f.read(100)
#g = io.open('simple.html', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
g = io.open('simple.html', 'w')
#g.write(webContent)
g.write(webContent.decode("UTF-8"))

g.close()
```

2019-01-11: See above for corrected working code after answers were received. Thanks guys.

---

Original question:
Upon execution, the file, simple.html, is created with 0 bytes.
Along with an error: 
**TypeError: must be str, not bytes.**
*Please help. I've gone about this several ways but to no avail.  Thank you in advance!*

Answer (score 0):

g.write(webContent.decode("utf-8"))

Comment: @A.Chan  accept the solution as an answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

File objects opened in text mode require you to write Unicode Text.

In this line you encoded to UTF-8 bytes

```
g = io.open('simple.html', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')
```

You could either not encode or try decoding it after.

Comment: I see now.  Thank you.